# Can I run GUI apps inside CoreOS?

Tags: containers, virtualbox, coreos

So I have CoreOS running inside a VirtualBox VM.

In the past, I have ran docker images that share the host X11 socket with the container to, for example, run a firefox GUI app.

Is this possible to do within my CoreOS VM?